# How to improve my algorithm time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

We have "n" files and for each file, "m" lines, we want to make some operations, to proceed all files and lines, it is evident to apply the algorithm below:

```
int n;    //n is the number of files 
int m;   //m is the number of the lines in the file i.
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            .....
   }
}
```

Thus, we have a O(nxm) complixity.

My question is :

Is there a possibility to make it O(nlog(n)), or other methods to improve the time complexity of the algorithm by :

1- keeping all files and lines.

2- we can ignore some of them.

Best regards

Comment: What language and platform is this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here - the code you provided will output 2 * N lines containing a single `*`. Is this meant to visualize how much "work" is done?

Comment: the code is only an example but my goal is to go from an algorithm with two loops that process all files and lines of files to an algorithm that processes only 50% or 70% of files

Comment: @hager I modify the question for more precision

Comment: @MEHDISAOUDI: your question is more fuzzy than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can achieve m log(n) by skipping n / log n files

or

2. You can achieve n log(m) by skipping m / log m lines per file.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to play with asymptotic complexities, then be rigorous.

The initial complexity is `Θ(F L)` (most probably, but you do not specify the processing) where `F` denotes the number of files and `L` the average number of lines per file. (Though, as the line lengths may vary, it would be safer to speak in terms of average number of characters.)

If you process as many files as there are bits in `F` (like you did), the complexity indeed lowers to `Θ(log(F) L)`. But if you process every other file, or even one tenth of them, the complexity remains `Θ(F L)`.

---

There is no magical recipe to reduce the complexity of a problem. Sometimes you can get improvements because the initial algorithm is not efficient, sometimes you cannot. In the case at hand, you probably cannot (though this depends on the particular processing).

What you are doing by subsampling the files is not a complexity improvement: it is a cheat to reduce the size of the problem, and you are no more solving the initial problem.

Comment: How can I improve the complexity in my case? knowing that I can neglect some files without processing them. My actual algorithm is like    
'for all files do {
 for all lines do { processing}
                  }'

Comment: @MEHDISAOUDI: what do you call "some files" ? Please be explicit. IMO, you are too much focused on "reducing the complexity" and you'd better tell us the real problem you are trying to solve. A smell of XY question.

Comment: it means that I can only process 50 or 40 of my 100 files in order to reduce the time complexity, but how to do it, is my problem

Comment: I have files, on each file there is a set of lines that I process them with a mathematical formula to have a signature that represents the file, the processing of 100 files takes me a huge time so I have to minimize the processing time  but I must also prove that theoretically, for that I'm trying to move to a different complexity than quadratic

Comment: I modify the question for more precision

Comment: @MEHDISAOUDI: I think that you disregarded my answer. Processing half of the files does not change the complexity.

Comment: on the contrary, I took your comment into consideration. What do you propose to me to improve the complexity?

Comment: there is nothing special